# datagridview1.SortCompare is ignored when executed by the program

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to do custom sorting for datagridview, But it's like he's just being ignored:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Index == 0)
    {
        if (double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) > double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
        {
            e.SortResult = 1;
        }
        else if (double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) < double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
        {
            e.SortResult = -1;
        }             
        else
        {
            e.SortResult = 0;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Specify where data is coming from and what the `ValueType` of the Column at index `0` is set to

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Index == 0)
    {
        double p1 = double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString());
        double p2 = double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString());
        e.SortResult = p1.CompareTo(p2);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```